# Error installing bundle listed in startup.properties with url: mvn:org.ops4j.pax.url/pax-url-aether/2.4.7

Tags: runtime-error, nexus, apache-karaf

I keep getting this error when i am trying to start nexus.

```
Error installing bundle listed in startup.properties with url: mvn:org.ops4j.pax.url/pax-url-aether/2.4.7 and startlevel: 1
        java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.karaf.main.Main.destroy(Main.java:593)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.karaf.NexusMain.main(NexusMain.java:55)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
              at 

sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
              at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
       at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:62)
      at 
     com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.main(UnixLauncher.java:63)
```

How to solve this?

Comment: What is the version of Nexus? Where did you get it from? bundles from startup.properties are started _specially_ by Karaf. For example pax-url-aether can't be resolved using `mvn:` scheme, because it's this bundles that handles this protocol

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the file permission is correct for your `nexus/system` folder? I have had a similar error, where `nexus/system` where owned by `root`, and not `nexus` which is the user I use to run Nexus.

I solved my problem by running `sudo chown nexus:nexus -R /opt/nexus/`.